# How to show a large size of an picture when the mouse is on it?

Tags: html, css

This is the image that shows what my website looks up to know:

[image: the iamge]

and I want that everytime I keep the mouse on a picture, that picture should be showed up in a large size. This is the code:

CSS:

```
    .container {
        position: relative;
        margin: 30px auto 0;
        height: 350px;
        width: 480px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
    }
    .container a {
        float: left;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    .thumb {
        position: relative;
        top: 250px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .big {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;  
        left: 1px;
        width: 500px;
        height:230px;
        -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
        -o-transition: top 1s ease;
        -ms-transition: top 1s ease;
        transition: top 1s ease;
    }
    a:hover .thumb {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    a:hover .big {

    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300">
        <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
        <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/dog">
        <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/dog">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/girl">
        <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/girl">
     </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/nature">
        <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/nature">
     </a>
   </div>
```

What to do?

Comment: Which image do you want to be big

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between two images in html with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184471/switch-between-two-images-in-html-with-css) and a multitude of similar answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated, having a text as well*

The simplest would be using `z-index` like this

```
a:hover .big {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  height: 350px;
  width: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}
.container a {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
.thumb {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}
.big {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;  
  left: 1px;
  width: 500px;
  height:230px;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
  -o-transition: top 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 1s ease;
  transition: top 1s ease;
}
div.big {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height:115px;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover .thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
a:hover .big {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300">
    <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300">
    <div class="big"> Hello there 1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
    <img class="big" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
    <div class="big"> Hello there 2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/dog">
    <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/dog">
    <div class="big"> Hello there 3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/girl">
    <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/girl">
    <div class="big"> Hello there 4</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/nature">
    <img class="big" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/300/nature">
    <div class="big"> Hello there 5</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I put text over the big picture?

Comment: @BogdanTomoiaga Updated my answer with text